# how to compare array index Value in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, indexing

i am newly to iphone. I am creating table based of iOS application. The problem is i need to navigate to the different view controller classes after tapping on the table rows. Basically i am receiving two vouchers values from server i.e. "eVoucher and "eGift", which is coming at run time. And i have total 3 view controller classes, if the voucher is "eVoucher" then i need to navigate to view controller "1", and if the value is "eGift" then i need to navigate to view controller "2" and its working fine, now the problem is if i am getting both "eVoucher and "eGift" in the list then how can i navigate to the view controller "3" class.

here is my code :

```
Catalogue *catalog = [[Catalogue alloc] init];// here Catalogue is my entity class

    for(int i=0;i<[arrayCheckout count];i++)
    {
        catalog = [arrayCheckout objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Catalogue Voucher Type = %@", catalog.voucherType);// i am getting here voucher type
    }
```

Please give me any suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a pretty inelegant way of doing it, but it should explain the logic as simply as possible:

```
Catalogue *catalog;

bool found_eVoucher = NO;
bool found_eGift = NO;

for(int i=0;i<[arrayCheckout count];i++) {
    catalog = [arrayCheckout objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Catalogue Voucher Type = %@", catalog.voucherType);// i am getting here voucher type

    if (catalog.voucherType == eVoucher) found_eVoucher = YES;
    if (catalog.voucherType == eGift) found_eGift = YES;
}

if (found_eVoucher && found_eGift) {
    // Navigate to controller 3
} else if (found_eVoucher) {
    // Navigate to controller 1
} else if (found_eGift) {
    // Navigate to controller 2
}
```